# show a div after loading another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two **div**

E.g.

```
<div class="first">
   //Div first content
</div>

<div class="second">
   //Div second contents
</div>
```

Initially div second is hidden . I want to show div "second" after loading div "first" with a delay.

[image]

I triend `$('first').load()` in jquery ,but it is not working.
I am completely new to jquery,how to do it in an efficient way

Comment: where is your scripts which tried so far

Comment: Do you need to show the second after a while, or showing second after the first one is actually loaded?

Comment: Not sure if it was just a typo in when copying it over, but you're missing the period in your class selector. You wrote  
    $('first').load() 
but it should be
    $('.first').load()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".second").delay(2000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for the first div to load before loading the second using either the .ready or .load methods provided by jQuery. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwagner/mvsxjvLy/) to see it in action.

```
.second {
  display: none;
}


$('.first').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.second').css("display", "block");
  }, 500);
});
```